# Beamer text centred with Polyglossia

Tags: beamer, xetex, polyglossia, alignment

I am using beamer and Polyglossia. Whenever I change the default language to Hebrew, the text in the slides is centred even without writing a single word in Hebrew.

The following MWE has to be compiled using XeLaTeX ---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{English frame}
This is my first english paragraph
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might try the `professionalfonts` option. But, does it work if you load English as the default language and select Hebrew where needed?

Comment: It also happens with `babel` and `xelatex`, which (like `polyglossia`) relies in turn in the `bidi` package. Works as expected with `babel`+`lualatex`, so I wonder if there is a bug in `bidi`. I think support for `beamer` is better with `babel`+`lualatex`, thanks to `beamer-lr`, but I'm the maintainer of `babel`, so I'm biased.